# I freeze jQuery data table table headings but unable to scroll How can i Scroll horizontally

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

**I used Jquery data table , i have this code, I need to freeze this table heading and scroll horizontally.**

I used this is Codeigniter framework, I make that modular format  HMVC.

```js
function list_all() {
  var tables;
  tables = $('#showdata').DataTable({

    "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
    "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
    "order": [], //Initial no order.

    // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
    "ajax": {
      "url": "<?php echo base_url() ?>cms/event_reporting_report_c/ajax_list",
      "type": "POST"
    },

    //Set column definition initialisation properties.
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": [0], //first column / numbering column
      "orderable": false, //set not orderable
    }, ],

    "dom": 'Bfrtip',
    "buttons": [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],

    "searching": true,
    "ordering": false,
    "paging": false,
    "info": false


  });
}
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Can you add relevant libraries, HTML and CSS to make a [mcve]?

Comment: I suggest you to repeat the main question at the very end of your contextualization. It makes it much more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the DataTables [horizontal scroll](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX) option with the DataTables [fixed headers](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/) extension.

If you include the required resources for fixed headers (see the demo below), then you can use these options in your DataTable:

```js
scrollX: true,
fixedHeader: true
```

Here is a self-contained, runnable demo:

```js
var dataSet = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Ashton Cox",
      "position": "Junior Technical Author",
      "salary": "$86,000",
      "start_date": "2009/01/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "1562"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Cedric Kelly",
      "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$433,060",
      "start_date": "2012/03/29",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "6224"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Airi Satou",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$162,700",
      "start_date": "2008/11/28",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "5407"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "name": "Brielle Williamson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$372,000",
      "start_date": "2012/12/02",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4804"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Herrod Chandler",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$137,500",
      "start_date": "2012/08/06",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "9608"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Rhona Davidson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$327,900",
      "start_date": "2010/10/14",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "6200"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Colleen Hurst",
      "position": "Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$205,500",
      "start_date": "2009/09/15",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2360"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Sonya Frost",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$103,600",
      "start_date": "2008/12/13",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "1667"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Jena Gaines",
      "position": "Office Manager",
      "salary": "$90,560",
      "start_date": "2008/12/19",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "3814"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Quinn Flynn",
      "position": "Support Lead",
      "salary": "$342,000",
      "start_date": "2013/03/03",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "9497"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Charde Marshall",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$470,600",
      "start_date": "2008/10/16",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "6741"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Haley Kennedy",
      "position": "Senior Marketing Designer",
      "salary": "$313,500",
      "start_date": "2012/12/18",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "3597"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Tatyana Fitzpatrick",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$385,750",
      "start_date": "2010/03/17",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "1965"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "Michael Silva",
      "position": "Marketing Designer",
      "salary": "$198,500",
      "start_date": "2012/11/27",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "1581"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Paul Byrd",
      "position": "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)",
      "salary": "$725,000",
      "start_date": "2010/06/09",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "3059"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Gloria Little",
      "position": "Systems Administrator",
      "salary": "$237,500",
      "start_date": "2009/04/10",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "1721"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Bradley Greer",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$132,000",
      "start_date": "2012/10/13",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "2558"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Dai Rios",
      "position": "Personnel Lead",
      "salary": "$217,500",
      "start_date": "2012/09/26",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "2290"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Jenette Caldwell",
      "position": "Development Lead",
      "salary": "$345,000",
      "start_date": "2011/09/03",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "1937"
    },
    {
      "id": "22",
      "name": "Yuri Berry",
      "position": "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)",
      "salary": "$675,000",
      "start_date": "2009/06/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "6154"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Caesar Vance",
      "position": "Pre-Sales Support",
      "salary": "$106,450",
      "start_date": "2011/12/12",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "8330"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Doris Wilder",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$85,600",
      "start_date": "2010/09/20",
      "office": "Sydney",
      "extn": "3023"
    },
    {
      "id": "25",
      "name": "Angelica Ramos",
      "position": "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "salary": "$1,200,000",
      "start_date": "2009/10/09",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "5797"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Gavin Joyce",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$92,575",
      "start_date": "2010/12/22",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "8822"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Jennifer Chang",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$357,650",
      "start_date": "2010/11/14",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "9239"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "Brenden Wagner",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$206,850",
      "start_date": "2011/06/07",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "1314"
    },
    {
      "id": "29",
      "name": "Fiona Green",
      "position": "Chief Operating Officer (COO)",
      "salary": "$850,000",
      "start_date": "2010/03/11",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2947"
    },
    {
      "id": "30",
      "name": "Shou Itou",
      "position": "Regional Marketing",
      "salary": "$163,000",
      "start_date": "2011/08/14",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8899"
    },
    {
      "id": "31",
      "name": "Michelle House",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$95,400",
      "start_date": "2011/06/02",
      "office": "Sydney",
      "extn": "2769"
    },
    {
      "id": "32",
      "name": "Suki Burks",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$114,500",
      "start_date": "2009/10/22",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "6832"
    },
    {
      "id": "33",
      "name": "Prescott Bartlett",
      "position": "Technical Author",
      "salary": "$145,000",
      "start_date": "2011/05/07",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "3606"
    },
    {
      "id": "34",
      "name": "Gavin Cortez",
      "position": "Team Leader",
      "salary": "$235,500",
      "start_date": "2008/10/26",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2860"
    },
    {
      "id": "35",
      "name": "Martena Mccray",
      "position": "Post-Sales support",
      "salary": "$324,050",
      "start_date": "2011/03/09",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "8240"
    },
    {
      "id": "36",
      "name": "Unity Butler",
      "position": "Marketing Designer",
      "salary": "$85,675",
      "start_date": "2009/12/09",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "5384"
    },
    {
      "id": "37",
      "name": "Howard Hatfield",
      "position": "Office Manager",
      "salary": "$164,500",
      "start_date": "2008/12/16",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "7031"
    },
    {
      "id": "38",
      "name": "Hope Fuentes",
      "position": "Secretary",
      "salary": "$109,850",
      "start_date": "2010/02/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "6318"
    },
    {
      "id": "39",
      "name": "Vivian Harrell",
      "position": "Financial Controller",
      "salary": "$452,500",
      "start_date": "2009/02/14",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "9422"
    },
    {
      "id": "40",
      "name": "Timothy Mooney",
      "position": "Office Manager",
      "salary": "$136,200",
      "start_date": "2008/12/11",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "7580"
    },
    {
      "id": "41",
      "name": "Jackson Bradshaw",
      "position": "Director",
      "salary": "$645,750",
      "start_date": "2008/09/26",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "1042"
    },
    {
      "id": "42",
      "name": "Olivia Liang",
      "position": "Support Engineer",
      "salary": "$234,500",
      "start_date": "2011/02/03",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "2120"
    },
    {
      "id": "43",
      "name": "Bruno Nash",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$163,500",
      "start_date": "2011/05/03",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "6222"
    },
    {
      "id": "44",
      "name": "Sakura Yamamoto",
      "position": "Support Engineer",
      "salary": "$139,575",
      "start_date": "2009/08/19",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "9383"
    },
    {
      "id": "45",
      "name": "Thor Walton",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$98,540",
      "start_date": "2013/08/11",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "8327"
    },
    {
      "id": "46",
      "name": "Finn Camacho",
      "position": "Support Engineer",
      "salary": "$87,500",
      "start_date": "2009/07/07",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2927"
    },
    {
      "id": "47",
      "name": "Serge Baldwin",
      "position": "Data Coordinator",
      "salary": "$138,575",
      "start_date": "2012/04/09",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "8352"
    },
    {
      "id": "48",
      "name": "Zenaida Frank",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$125,250",
      "start_date": "2010/01/04",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "7439"
    },
    {
      "id": "49",
      "name": "Zorita Serrano",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$115,000",
      "start_date": "2012/06/01",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "4389"
    },
    {
      "id": "50",
      "name": "Jennifer Acosta",
      "position": "Junior Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$75,650",
      "start_date": "2013/02/01",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "3431"
    },
    {
      "id": "51",
      "name": "Cara Stevens",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$145,600",
      "start_date": "2011/12/06",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "3990"
    },
    {
      "id": "52",
      "name": "Hermione Butler",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$356,250",
      "start_date": "2011/03/21",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "1016"
    },
    {
      "id": "53",
      "name": "Lael Greer",
      "position": "Systems Administrator",
      "salary": "$103,500",
      "start_date": "2009/02/27",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "6733"
    },
    {
      "id": "54",
      "name": "Jonas Alexander",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$86,500",
      "start_date": "2010/07/14",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "8196"
    },
    {
      "id": "55",
      "name": "Shad Decker",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$183,000",
      "start_date": "2008/11/13",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "6373"
    },
    {
      "id": "56",
      "name": "Michael Bruce",
      "position": "Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$183,000",
      "start_date": "2011/06/27",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "5384"
    },
    {
      "id": "57",
      "name": "Donna Snider",
      "position": "Customer Support",
      "salary": "$112,000",
      "start_date": "2011/01/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4226"
    }
  ];
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        pageLength: 50, // just for testing/demo
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "ID", data: "id" },
            { title: "Name", data: "name" },
            { title: "Office", data: "office" },
            { title: "Position", data: "position" },
            { title: "Start date", data: "start_date" },
            { title: "Extn.", data: "extn" },
            { title: "Salary", data: "salary" }
        ],
        scrollX: true,
        fixedHeader: true
    } );
} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.2.4/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.2.4/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:120%">
    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Looking at the following screen shot...

[image]

... you can see the headers remain at the top of the vertically scrolled page, and the horizontal scroll bar is visible at the bottom of the table (underneath the final row in the table).

You can add your specific customizations (your columns, Ajax data source, and other settings) to this approach.